# suspect ODBC configure error in SQLSERVER

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use python to connect SQLSERVER on Windows 7-64 bit

My code is as follows:

```
self.conn  = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=MY-PC/SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Webmining;UID=sara;PWD=xxxxxx")
```

And the error is as follows:

> pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]SQ L Server
>   \xb2\xbb\xb4\xe6\xd4\xda\xbb\xf2\xb7\xc3\xce\xca\xb1\xbb\xbe\xdc\xbe\xf
>   8 (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB] ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')

Upon checking MSDN, 08001 means 'Unable to connect to data source', while 01000 means 'General warning'.

I looked heaps of similar questions, It pointed to ODBC. My ODBC driver version is SQL Server Native Client 11.0, my SQL Server is 2008 R2

Could someone give me some suggestion?